# Issue with zlib compression in file seek scenario, Is any locking / flag mechanism available in zlib that aloow integrity between those

Tags: c, linux, compression, gzip, zlib

I am working on project that deal with larger file , In our code base we do back seek to write certian information, these seeks are very smaller range most of the time, I thought to use zlib in my stream writer /reader just to save disk space, but due to such seek things i am not able to integrate it , because for that i need to write in buffer first then compress buffer and write it back, that is hectic in very old/ clutter code base. Easy way is to provide my stream writer gzlib file handle and gzlib writer api it will write automatically , but will stuck / unsure in seek scenario, that lead disater for me. I am looking for a mechanism so that i can tell zlib (locking/atomic) like hey dont compress it until unlock/flag , in such a way seek on internal buffer will take not on compressed one and my data and code base will be less intact.
Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is, sorry.

Comment: Problem is i am using zlib api to compress my data sequentially, as data arrive , just send it for compress. But I encountered some scenario where i have to seek back and write the data in my file.
Now i am not sure about consistency of this seek with zlib, So i was wondering , Is there any flag/ locking mechanism in zlib so that i can signal zlib put this in buffer don't write it immediately or until i signaled you, we might need seek and once seek done , i signalled back so that zlib compress and write it.

Comment: Does it help in understanding problem ? @immibis

Comment: You can't seek in a compressed file. Full stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't seek back and write over a gzip stream. gzip is intended only for sequential use, both reading and writing.

There is a `gzseek()` function in zlib, but it is very limited in what it does and how it does it. When writing, you can only seek forward, in which case the intermediate uncompressed bytes are filled with zeros. You can seek forward and backward when reading. However seeking backward is very slow, as it will rewind all the way back to the beginning of the file and then read through the whole thing to the desired position.